# I want to calculate a value into a table but it only gives me a result of one column

Tags: jquery

I want to calculate a value in jQuery into a table using `each()`, `eq()` and `text()`. My code only gives me a result of one column

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  $("tr").each(function() {

    var num1 = $("td").eq(0).text();
    var num2 = $("td").eq(2).text();
    var rslt = parseFloat(num1) + parseFloat(num2);

    $("td").eq(4).text(rslt);

  });
});
```

```css
* {}

div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: lightgray;
}

.table tr td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px
}

.table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}

th {
  background: lightgreen
}

td {
  background: lightblue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>#target
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Num1</th>
      <th>oper</th>
      <th>Num2</th>
      <th> equals</th>
      <th> Answer</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>42 </td>
      <td>+ </td>
      <td>12 </td>
      <td>= </td>
      <td>? </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>15 </td>
      <td>+ </td>
      <td>87 </td>
      <td>= </td>
      <td>?</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td>102 </td>
      <td>+ </td>
      <td>25 </td>
      <td>= </td>
      <td>?</td>
    </tr>


  </table>


  <br>

  <button id="btn">calcu</button>
</div>
```

Here is my code: codepen.io/yassine_hammadi/pen/rNWxqJe

Comment: Please put all relevant code in the question. Use the snippet editor (the `[<>]` button) to create a working example

Comment: Sorry I am just new here, still trying to get as much as possible in the platform, I know I would laugh on this comment and the way I posted my question after some couple of years. we are all here to learn. thank you my friend, and I would really appreciate your help as I do with your previous advice. I reposted my question in a comment below, you can have a look and help me out. thank you

Comment: Use the `edit` button under your question to add the code, do not put it in an answer. I've done it for you in this case. I would suggest you delete the answer you added.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is because you select all the `td` in to a single jQuery object. When you try to update the text of a collection, jQuery will only update the first element in that collection.

To fix this you need to amend your code to find the `td` within the `tr` in the loop. To do that you can use the `this` keyword to refer to the `tr` in the iteration, and then `find()`. Try this:

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  $("tr").each(function() {
    let $tr = $(this);
    let num1 = $tr.find("td:eq(0)").text();
    let num2 = $tr.find("td:eq(2)").text();
    let rslt = parseFloat(num1) + parseFloat(num2);
    $tr.find("td:eq(4)").text(rslt);
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: lightgray;
}

.table tr td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px
}

.table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}

th { background: lightgreen; }
td { background: lightblue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Num1</th>
      <th>oper</th>
      <th>Num2</th>
      <th> equals</th>
      <th> Answer</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>42</td>
      <td>+</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>=</td>
      <td>?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>+</td>
      <td>87</td>
      <td>=</td>
      <td>?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>102</td>
      <td>+</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>=</td>
      <td>?</td>
    </tr>
  </table><br>
  <button id="btn">calcu</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you my friend I really appreciate that. @Rory McCrossan I hope you have good rest of day.

Comment: You know Rory! I have another question but I don't wanna be like wasting your time. I didn't understand this ( $tr) If you can send med me a video explaining that it would be awesome, I don't wanna bother you by explaining it to me. thank you Rory

Comment: Ops I just wanted to jump to another line then the message was sent, sorry

Comment: `$tr` is just a variable name. The `$` prefix is a naming convention to show that the variable holds a jQuery object, not a string, or int, or any other type.

Comment: it's totally clear now, thank you very much my friend, all the answers were helpful. is there anything like follow or rate in this platform, I wanna make sure that I am following you Sir.

Comment: There's no way to follow users, all you can do it upvote and accept their answers :)